# Can't get easy-thumbnails nor sorl to work on mac, no errors generated

Tags: python, django, sorl-thumbnail, python-imaging-library, easy-thumbnails

I'm trying to get easy-thumbnails to generate thumbnails using django 1.6.2 on a mac (darwin 2.7.5).

I'll detail below my settings for easy_thumbnails, I have also tried with sorl - no debug was generated for either (THUMBNAIL_DEBUG = True).  Easy-thumbnails does nothing (no error, doesn't write to db, produces no url).  Sorl produces a bad request 400 error, and there is no other debug to go on.

Here's what I do.

```
#settings.py
THUMBNAIL_DEBUG = True  
INSTALLED_APPS = ('easy_thumbnails',)
THUMBNAIL_ALIASES = {
'': {
    '40x40': {'size': (40, 40), 'crop': True}, 
    '100x100': {'size': (100, 100), 'crop': True},
    '250x250': {'size': (250, 250), 'crop': True},
},
}

#after pip install pillow
--- TKINTER support available
--- JPEG support available
--- ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support available
--- LIBTIFF support available
--- FREETYPE2 support available
*** LITTLECMS2 support not available
--- WEBP support available
--- WEBPMUX support available
```

From 'pip freeze'

```
Django==1.6.2
Pillow==2.3.0
easy-thumbnails==1.5
```

Runnng:

```
python manage.py migrate easy_thumbnails
```

Go to template and try the following:

```
#template
{% load thumbnail %}
<img src="{{ request.user.picture|thumbnail_url:'250x250' }}" alt="" />
<!-- without thumbnail, pic is visible here -->
<img class="profile_pic" src="{{ request.user.picture }}" alt="" />
```

Result:

```
Nothing and no errors!
```

Edit:  I should also add i did the following:

```
$ ./manage.py shell
>>> from easy_thumbnails.files import get_thumbnailer
>>> opts = {'size': (966, 300), 'replace_alpha': '#fff', 'autocrop': True, 'crop': True, 'upscale': True}
>>> get_thumbnailer(open('your_image.png'), 'put.png').generate_thumbnail(opts).image.show()
```

And there were no errors.  I assume the problem is elsewhere and nothing to do with pillow?
I'm at a complete loss as to what is causing this. I know, at some point, easy_thumbnails was working as i had data in the database.  Something has clearly broken it but without any debug I'm a at a bit of a loss to know where to go next.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: That may seem trivial but are you sure request.user is not anonymous?

Comment: Try enabling THUMBNAIL_DEBUG to see the traceback of the error, by default is errors are silent

Comment: Sorry i can't remember how i solved it but of course it was not a problem with either sorl or thumbnails.  I suggest you try using django shell to thumbnail and see if that works.